# Some default eloquent-relationships for this?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables: `applications`, `countries`, `suppliers`:

**applications:**

```
id
id_supplier
id_country
```

**countries:**

```
id
```

**suppliers:**

```
id
```

So what i need from here is to get all the `countries` a given supplier has developed an application.

I tried manually taking advantage of the applications model, and a method on the suppliers model:

**Application.php (model):**

```
...
public function country() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'id_country');
}
...
```

**Supplier.php (model):**

```
...
public function applications() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Application', 'id_supplier');
}
public function countries() {
    $apps = $this->applications()->get();
    $countries = array();
    foreach ($apps as $app) {
        $countries[] = $app->country;
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

Which got me the fallowing error:

> Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation

I also tried on the Supplier Model:

```
...
$this->hasManyThrough('App\Country', 'App\Application', 'id_country', 'id_supplier');
...
```

Giving column not found `counties.id_supplier` (obviously), is this possible using `hasManyThrough` relation? If yes, what am i doing wrong? Or i should choose a different way/relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your controller:

```
public function countries() {
    $apps = $this->applications;
    $countries = array();
    foreach ($apps as $app) {
        $countries[] = $app->country;
    }
    return $countries;
}
```

Comment: Thnaks, but got the same error `Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation` . If i dump `$countries` before the return the data is ok

Comment: Yeh, i wanted to avoid that... Change your anwser to say "Try this on controller". If no one else come up with a better solution i will accept your answer. Thanks Alex

Comment: Hmm, I tried in my model and it works. How do you try it? You should use with parentheses: `$supplier->countries()`

Comment: Try to rename `id` in countries and suppliers tables to `id_country` and `id_supplier`

Comment: Actualy i change it to my model and used `countries()` with parentesis, it worked either way (: thanks